# Using BigQuery with bigrquery is much more expensive

Tags: google-bigquery, billing

I've been using BQ through the web UI for a few weeks and my daily charge has always been sub-cents. Now I found [bigrquery](https://github.com/rstats-db/bigrquery), which makes life easier (remote table construction and not having to go through the cloud interface to pull data sets locally) but suddenly I'm getting charged a lot more for the same queries.

I thought maybe it could be the non-compressed data downloading (but why would that be more expensive?) or that bigrquery doesn't limit the billing tier (but why would the same query in the web UI be cheaper?).

Any ideas and how I can go around it?

Comment: as @Pentium10 says, more details are needed...

Answer (score 1):

Enable audit logs and you will have way to detect what is causing your increase.

To analyze your aggregated usage data using SQL, set up export of audit logs back to BigQuery. For more information about setting up exports from Cloud Logging, see Overview of Logs Export in the [Cloud Logging documentation](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/configure_export_v2).

Analyzing Audit Logs Using BigQuery: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/audit-logs